# Solution for well-encrypted group messaging, on Android inside Knox

Tags: encryption, privacy, instant-messaging, xmpp, otr

I am looking to setup a **secure messaging system** to be used among friends.

Ideally it would be **cross-platform** (Android-phones using the Knox-container, laptops, Android-tablets with Knox) and support **group chats** as well as the transfer of pictures. It is vital that it is **end-to-end encrypted**. We would like to set up our **own server** (XMPP ??), to stay 'out-of-the-cloud'.

I looked on EFF's website (here: [EFF](https://www.eff.org/node/82654)) to see what Apps are available and subsequently looked into installing servers for those that score 'all green'.

I did not find what I wanted though:

- ChatSecure: can run own server, but uses OTR-protocol, so no end-to-end encrypted groupchats
- Pidgin: no client for Android
- Signal/SilentText/SilentPhone: does support e2e groupchatting, but not possible to set up own server
- Telegram: servercode online but very limited documentation found
- TextSecure: OTR, so no e2e-groupchats

So now I am inclining towards a well-secured, well-encrypted IRC-server, possibly running the OTR-plugin.

Did anyone else ever encounter the same problem ? What way did you go ?

Comment: You could take a look at this: https://github.com/siacs/Conversations
It might fit your needs :)